# Template does not exist after splitting the settings in Django

Tags: python, django

This is my Traceback error:
[image: Here is the traceback error].

All was working well before I split the settings (development, production). Now I am having an issue with the template doesn't exist. Here are my settings files:

**`base_settings.py`:**

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 
'../../'))

INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'autoslug',
'accounts',
'stellar',
'stellar_sdk',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'stellarLedger.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'stellarLedger.wsgi.application'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'email username'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "accounts.customUser"

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
  'default': {
     'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
     'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
 }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
 {
    'NAME': 
'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
 },
 {
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
 },
 {
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
 },
 {
    'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
 },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

**`development_settings.py`**

```
from .base_settings import *

SECRET_KEY = 'secret key'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.168.0.102', '127.0.0.1']
```

**`production_settings.py`**

```
from .base_settings import *

DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['mysite.com', 'ip.of.my.site', 'www.mysite.com', ]
```

What am I doing wrong here? The template that is not found is in root template directory.

here is my project structure:

- project/

  - project

    - **init**.py
    - settings

      - **init**.py
      - base_settings.py
      - development_settings.py
      - production_settings.py
    - wsgi.py
    - asgi.py
  - accounts

    - templates

      - accounts

        - test.html
  - templates

    - base.html
    - index.html
  - static

Comment: Could you print ```BASE_DIR``` and see if it's pointing to the correct directory ?

Comment: BASE_DIR is the project root directory

Comment: I know that. Just ```print(BASE_DIR)``` and check if it's pointing to the correct path. You need to thoroughly check your project directory structure.

Comment: It's printing this `/home/nasir/Documents/stellarLedger`. stellarLedger is my project name. What should it print?

Comment: Could you post an image of  project directory structure.

Comment: @NasirHussain Welcome to SO. Please don't post error message or such as an image. That way search engines can't index it. Also your question won't be accessible to many impaired people. I could list many more drawbacks, so please, just post it as text ;)

Comment: @Ram I have added the project structure. It may not be looking pretty as I don't know how to show structure here in SO

Answer (score 0):

You changed the default name of `settings.py`. Revert back all the changes of `settings.py` and add this line after `DEBUG = True`:

```
productions_hosts = ['mysite.com', 'ip.of.my.site', 'www.mysite.com']
development_hosts = ['192.168.0.102', '127.0.0.1']

ALLOWED_HOSTS = development_hosts if DEBUG else productions_hosts
```

And one more thing, **KEEP THE SECRET KEY SECRET!**